# Disable CPUs on boot but allow hotplug in Xen

Tags: xen, central-processing-unit, vcpu

I would like to create a Xen VM with 32 possible VCPUs but have the guest OS only enable 2 of them on boot. Are there some kernel parameters I can pass in to enable this? I've played around with various combinations of `additional_cpus`, `disabled_cpus`, and `possible_cpus` and I can't seem to find anything that works.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps I need to start spending more time working on my own before asking questions. I solved this issue by setting the `vcpu_avail` mask in the Xen config file to 3.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty new to Xen too, but seems like there are two Xen variables that you can set. Doing a `xe vm-param-list uuid=<uuid>` yields the following two variables:

```
VCPUs-max ( RW): 1
VCPUs-at-startup ( RW): 1
```

Seems like you would want to set the first one to 32 and the second one to 2 for your specific guest OS.

Comment: I should add that I'm using the open source version of Xen, not the one from Citrix, so this doesn't help.